# AKS nginx-ingress controller ACR

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I'm unable to install the nginx ingress controller on AKS.Since I'm using `userDefinedRouting` as `outboundType` for egress when running
`helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress -n ingress --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"='"true"' --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet"=x-x-x-aks-ingress-sub01 --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="10.240.137.40"` i can see that it failed to download the image because the root CA is not on the worker node and hence is unable to verify the SSL certificate. This is actually good and I've uploaded the nginx image to my ACR:
`docker pull nginx` `docker tag nginx/nginx-ingress:2.2.2 nameofacr.azurecr.io/hub/nginx/nginx-ingress:2.2.2` and `docker push nameofacr.azurecr.io/hub/nginx/nginx-ingress:2.2.2`. If it look in the `values.yaml` file I see this:
[values.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O44PW.png) I've followed [how to - helm install using private registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58719627/how-to-helm-install-using-private-registry) and think that I've added the tag as required but I can't figure out how to run the command now so that it will pull the image from my ACR.

What I've tried:

`helm install nginx-ingress nameofacr.azurecr.io/hub/nginx/nginx-ingress -n ingress --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\ .kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"='"true"' --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet"=x-x-x-x-aks-ingress-sub01 --set contro ller.service.loadBalancerIP="10.240.137.40"`
failed with `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to download "nameofacr.azurecr.io/hub/nginx/nginx-ingress"`

or

`helm install nginx-ingress --set Image=nameofacr.azurecr.io nginx/nginx-ingress  -n ingress --set controller.service.annotations."servi ce\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"='"true"' --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet"=x-x-x-x-aks-ingress-sub01 --s et controller.service.loadBalancerIP="10.240.137.40"` resulted in `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to download "nginx/nginx-ingress"`

I can't get this to work. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Use this chart : ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx. You have an [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic) that explain how to import images to private ACR.

You can use this commands to import images :

```
az acr import --name nameofacr --source k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.2.1 --force
az acr import --name nameofacr --source k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1 --force
```

Also try to fix the helm chart version `helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --version 4.1.3`, to be sure you use the images related to a specific [values.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/helm-chart-4.1.3/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml).